# Inspect HTML5 date picker shadow DOM

Tags: html, html-input, shadow-dom

I'm trying to inspect the shadow DOM for certain HTML5 controls, like the date picker for the `input type="date"` and the actual suggestion dropdown list for inputs bound to a `datalist`. Preferably in Chrome, but other browsers will do too.

I've found that by enabling the Shadow DOM setting in Chrome's inspector options allows me to inspect the shadow DOM for the actual `input` (which includes the `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` arrow to show the datepicker) but not the datepicker itself:

[image]

The same goes for the `datalist`. It appears as these controls are not part of the input, but I also can't find them anywhere else in the elements panel.

Is it possible to inspect such elements?

Small edit for clarification: I'm actually looking for which pseudo-classes apply to which controls. There's plenty of sites that list some of them, but I have yet to find a source that manages to list `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` for the `datalist` element, which does get applied. I'm looking for more of those sneaky bastards, and the best source for that of course is the horse's mouth.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like the actual picker is loaded in an entirely different layer (basically a different window without the titlebar). So I guess the answer is: no, you can't.

[image]

I agree it would be great to be able to customize it. And similar popups too. Mozilla in XUL has `display:popup` which is used by context menus, flyout and similar things. Would be definitely great being able to use that in userland content too.

Comment: That's a shame, thanks. I'm really not even looking to customize it, but just to inspect its structure and see what pseudo-classes are applied to it.

Answer (score 11):

The calendar popup of Google Chrome is not in Shadow DOM.
It's in a separated page mapped to a popup window. See [WebPagePopupImpl.cpp](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/web/WebPagePopupImpl.cpp)

And the popup content is [written by HTML/JavaScript](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/web/resources/).

Comment: Interesting! The only thing I can't seem to find in the source code you linked is the HTML it is built of. Of all the things I can see in there, the pseudo-classes that are used seem to be missing. Are they present anywhere in the code?