# JavaScript open input date picker event

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I am trying to open a date calendar input when a change event is activated.

There is a drop down field, and when a user clicks the "Specific Date" option, I would like the calendar to actually open up, however I have not been successful thus far.

The area I am wanting to open the calendar, I have added the comment: 'Below is what I have tried to open the date picker calendar'.

```js
const datePickerEl = document.getElementById("js_datePickerToggle");

const hideDatePicker = () => {
  datePickerEl.classList.add("displayNone");
};

const getDateRange = (option) => {
  if (option === 'Today') {
    hideDatePicker();
  } else {
    // display datepicker
    datePickerEl.classList.remove("displayNone");

    /*
      * Below is what I have tried to open the date picker calendar
      * datePickerEl.focus();
      * datePickerEl.click();
      * datePickerEl.select();
    */
  }
}

const dateOptionEls = document.getElementsByName("dateRange");

dateOptionEls[0].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const optionValue = dateOptionEls[0].options[dateOptionEls[0].selectedIndex].text;
  getDateRange(optionValue);
});
```

```css
.displayNone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Date</label>
  <select name="dateRange" dateRange=''>
    <option value="Today">Today</option>
    <option type="date" value="Specific date">Specific Date
      <input type="date" id="js_datePickerToggle" class="displayNone">
    </option>  
  </select>
</div>
```

Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research I found this answer to the date input element in general:
[Inspect HTML5 date picker shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842645/inspect-html5-date-picker-shadow-dom)

As described there, the shown datepicker element is some kind of separate window and it seems that you cannot call it direclty.

So the answer is: no you cannot open the datepicker. You should use some JavaScript based DateTimePickers. I could recommend flatpickr or pickmeup, they are made in Vanilla JavaScript and are very lightweight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it pointed me in the right direction. I ended up using pikaday to get the job done.

Comment: It's attached to the DOM in closed mode, so there is no access to the shadow DOM

Answer (score 18):

You can open the picker with `inputElement.showPicker()` if it's of the type `<input type="datetime-local">`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker

Comment: Thanks I have been looking for this answer for a long time, thankssss

Comment: A warning that this does not work on Safari on iOS (https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlinputelement_showpicker_date_input). Tested it locally and confirmed this is currently not supported, despite the MDN compatibility table.

Comment: @icanfathom can confirm in 2023. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Is there any alternate for safari?