# How to handle html date picker having type="date" using selenium , on date selection no change in html dom

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I am trying to handle the html based date picker, I am able to click on it so that the date picker calendar pop up, but there is no inspect option for calendar.

Even when i manually select the date there is no such change in the HTML DOM, that can be used.
i tried adding date inside it using following workaround, none of them worked(no  ,  thing happening in DOM).

```js
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('date-input').value='10101990'"); 
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
driver.findElement(By.id("date-input")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

In web it appears as editable along with select from calendar option(run the code snippet below)
while in mobile (web) its appearance is different as shown in screenshot.

is there any solution with JAVA-Selenium : [Inspect HTML5 date picker shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842645/inspect-html5-date-picker-shadow-dom)

[image]

```html
<label for="start">Start date:</label>
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       min="2020-01-01" max="2020-12-31" value>
```

```html
<input class="Input-module_input__nj1kl" type="date" id="date-input" data-testid="date-input" placeholder="Date of Birth" required="" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="birth-date-input-error" aria-required="true" min="1920-01-01" max="2020-08-18" value>
<label for="date-input" class="Input-module_label__npqrt1">Date of Birth*</label><label for="date-input" class="Input-module_label__30ytr">Date of Birth*</label>
<span role="alert" id="date-input-error" class="Input-module_errorMessage__lMKY" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid date of birth</span>
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the `shadow DOM`

Comment: i do not see a #shadow linked with this input tag in html, i have gone through lot many similar queries , showing similar behavior(linking it with shadow dom). i have just updated the exact html of calendar

Answer (score 0):

Below Code sample have worked for me.Update your required date in format `yyyy-MM-dd`  for the variable `date`

```java
    driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8887/");
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
    String date="2009-02-09";
    js.executeScript("document.getElementById('date-input').value ='"+date.toString()+"'",2000);
```

Change your required `Id` in `getElementById('date-input')` inside the js executor

Comment: yes it is writing the content(date) in the date picker input box , but it does not remains there as i click on any other functionality like check box. reason being when i click on submit date disappears from the form.

Comment: @TEST-M As you have posted only this particular DOM element. I have provided answer for this if the problem is from your form the post the respective html code

Answer (score 0):

Well... I can simply tell you the simple logic

1. By default when the calendar opens then-current date is selected
2. You need to check if current date is less or greater than date to be selected. Date.compareTo function will help here
3. Then you need to navigate to the corresponding month and year combination.
4. Once you are in the right month and year then you can select the date as well.